"Import "tensorflow.models" could not be resolvedPylance"
When I run the code, I get the error shown in the attached picture.
How can I overcome this error? The code is the front part of an ANN analysis code. It gives an R2 and RMSE value as a result, but I doubt I'm doing something wrong. I wrote is as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.optimizers import Adam


These imports do not exist, it should be tensorflow.keras.models, etc.

You can try two methods to solve this problem. The first method is importing keras via TensorFlow correctly. If you are working with tensorflow this is the best method.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam

Also, you can import directly from the Keras library. If you are working in the backend, you should try this method.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.optimizers import Adam

